# Helm --namespace command not found?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

This helm command is throwing namespace error: --namespace command not found

`helm upgrade $HELM_CHART_NAME ./chart --install --values=./chart/$ENVIRONMENT.yaml --set secrets.env_vars.DB_URI={$DB_URI}?retryWrites=true&w=majority --namespace $KUBE_NAMESPACE --create-namespace`

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `&` in your `secrets.env_vars.DB_URI` setting effectively starts a new command in bash. Wrap the argument (or at least the last part of it) in quotes, eg `--set "secrets.env_vars.DB_URI=.....&w=majority"`.